# How to find errors related to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

"We are maintaining two instances lets name it x and y,a module in the application code perfectly working in x but not in instance-y although it contains same code except database"

So I moved my db of y into x and then instance-x failed to execute that specific code then i concluded  problem with db , if so how to check the problem that occured in db?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it was not a code sample, so removed it.

Comment: It can also be a problem how you have configured and connected to your mongodb from your code sample. You need to provide additional info about your application code, what env (apache, linux, etc) before you can jump to conclusions